# Метод sort_value() в pandas сортирует по 1-му разряду

Tags: python, pandas

Метод `sort_values` в `pandas` сортирует по первой цифре (разряду). 
Т.е. по убывающей последовательность `(3, 18, 8, 12, 24, 4)` будет выстроена `(8, 4, 3, 24, 18, 12)`.

Вопрос: как сделать нормальную сортировку вида `(24, 18, 12, 8, 4, 2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделал бы через Series. Такой тип данных подходит?

```
In [1]: data = (3, 18, 8, 12, 24, 4)

In [2]: type(data)   # Проверим тип последовательности, это кортеж
Out[2]: tuple

In [3]: import pandas as pd

In [4]: new_data = pd.Series(data)    # Преобразуем в Series

In [5]: type(new_data)    # Проверим тип
Out[5]: pandas.core.series.Series
In [6]: new_data.sort_values(ascending=False)    # Сортируем последовательность по убыванию
Out[6]: 
4    24
1    18
3    12
2     8
5     4
0     3
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Тоже корректный работающий способ, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Преобразуйте Series к числовому типу.

Пример:

```
In [9]: df
Out[9]:
    n
0   3
1  18
2   8
3  12
4  24
5   4

In [10]: df.dtypes
Out[10]:
n    object     # <---------- !!!
dtype: object

In [11]: df.sort_values('n', ascending=False)
Out[11]:
    n
2   8
5   4
0   3
4  24
1  18
3  12
```

Преобразование типа:

```
In [12]: df['n'] = pd.to_numeric(df['n'], errors='coerce')
```

Результат:

```
In [13]: df.sort_values('n', ascending=False)
Out[13]:
    n
4  24
1  18
3  12
2   8
5   4
0   3

In [14]: df.dtypes
Out[14]:
n    int64     # <---------- !!!
dtype: object
```

Comment: Спасибо!!!!11111